# iOS Swift UICollectionView registerNib for reuseable view not working

Tags: ios, swift, nib, collectionview, reuseidentifier

I am trying to use a create a iCalendar lookalike using a UICollectionViewController. Right now I am trying to add reuseable views as column headers for each day.

I made a storyboard and added a UICollectionViewController which is linked to this class:

```
import UIKit

class WeekViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    let dataSource = WeekViewDataSource()
    let weekLayout = WeekViewLayout()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var columnHeaderViewNIB = UINib(nibName: "ColumnHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        self.collectionView?.registerNib(columnHeaderViewNIB, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: columnHeaderViewIdentifier, withReuseIdentifier: columnHeaderViewIdentifier)

        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = weekLayout
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = dataSource

        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

The ColumnHeaderView nib is actually a xib file with a view containing a single label. This view is linked to this class:

```
import UIKit

class ColumnHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

The datasource and the layout:

```
import UIKit

class WeekViewDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var events = Array<String>()

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var view: UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: kind, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionReusableView

        configureHeader(view, kind: kind, indexPath: indexPath)

        return view
    }

    func configureHeader(view: UICollectionReusableView, kind: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if kind == columnHeaderViewIdentifier
        {
            let interval = NSTimeInterval(indexPath.item * 24 * 60 * 60)
            let now = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)
            let format = NSDateFormatter()
            format.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
            format.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
            format.locale = NSLocale()
            format.dateFormat = "EE\ndd. MMMM"

            let headerView: ColumnHeaderView = view as ColumnHeaderView

            headerView.label.text = format.stringFromDate(now)
        }
    }
}




class WeekViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout
{
    var DaysPerWeek = 7
    var HoursPerDay = 24
    var HeightPerHour: CGFloat = 60.0
    var DayHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    var DayHeaderWidth: CGFloat = 120.0
    var HourHeaderWidth: CGFloat = 50.0

    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        var contentWidth = HourHeaderWidth + DayHeaderHeight * CGFloat(DaysPerWeek)
        var contentHeight = DayHeaderHeight + HeightPerHour * CGFloat(HoursPerDay)

        return CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
        var layoutAttributes = Array<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()

        // Column Header - Days
        var dayHeaderViewIndexPaths = indexPathsOfDayHeaderViewsInRect(rect)
        for indexPath in dayHeaderViewIndexPaths
        {
            var attributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(columnHeaderViewIdentifier, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }

        return layoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        var attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: elementKind, withIndexPath: indexPath)

        if elementKind == columnHeaderViewIdentifier
        {
            attributes.frame = CGRectMake(
                HourHeaderWidth + DayHeaderWidth * CGFloat(indexPath.length),
                self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y,
                DayHeaderWidth,
                DayHeaderHeight)
        }

        return attributes
    }


    func indexPathsOfDayHeaderViewsInRect(frame: CGRect) -> [NSIndexPath]
    {
        var minDayIndex = dayIndexFromXCoord(CGRectGetMinX(frame))
        var maxDayIndex = dayIndexFromXCoord(CGRectGetMaxX(frame))

        var indexPaths = Array<NSIndexPath>()
        for i in (minDayIndex...maxDayIndex)
        {
            indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(index: i))
        }

        return indexPaths
    }


    /*
        Helper methods
    */

    func dayIndexFromXCoord(positionX: CGFloat) -> Int
    {
        var contentWidth = collectionViewContentSize().width - HourHeaderWidth
        var widthPerDay = contentWidth / CGFloat(DaysPerWeek)
        return Int(max(0.0, (positionX - HourHeaderWidth) / widthPerDay))
    }
}
```

I am not that far yet because I am stuck at a very basic problem.

```
The ViewController doesn't register the nib and I always get this error:
2014-09-22 22:49:52.242 WeekView[4973:304060] *** Assertion failure in -[WeekView.WeekViewLayout _decorationViewForLayoutAttributes:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318/UICollectionViewLayout.m:1292
2014-09-22 22:49:52.244 WeekView[4973:304060] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a decoration view of kind: ColumnHeaderView - must register as a class or nib or connect a prototype in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100aa13f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102812bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100aa125a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010117b28f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000101bb699a -[UICollectionViewLayout _decorationViewForLayoutAttributes:] + 872
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000101b982e6 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 413
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000101b994da -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3483
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000101b9d161 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 243
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001015e7199 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000105f6cf98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105f61bbe _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105f61a2e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105ecfade _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105ed0bea _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010156c67d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010156d368 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2642
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010156bd22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010507d2a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001009d6abc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001009cc805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001009cbfc3 __CFRunLoopRun + 851
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001009cba06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010156b799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010156e550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    24  WeekView                            0x00000001008afc0e top_level_code + 78
    25  WeekView                            0x00000001008afc4a main + 42
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102fdd145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Why is this happening?
Am I missing anything?

Any help would be appreachiated :) Thank you in advance

EDIT:
I found the problem!
This line was wrong:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: elementKind, withIndexPath: indexPath)
```

I tried to get the ViewLayoutAttributes for a decoration view but it is registered as a reuseable view. I changed this line and it works again.

Comment: How you change your line? I have the same issue

Comment: I changed it to UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, withIndexPath: indexPath) because it is a supplementary view not a decoration view

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that your layout is requesting layout attributes for a *decoration* view, but you're registering the NIB for a *supplementary* view. This can be a bit confusing because the `UICollectionViewLayout` object does NOT correspond with its delegates when creating decoration views, it just creates them in the knowledge that their physical appearance is not informed by the content of the collection.

For this reason, decoration views are registered with the `UICollectionViewLayout` function `registerNib: forDecorationViewOfKind:` not `UICollectionView` itself.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your outlet isn't set at the time you call registerNib method. Move your code to viewDidLoad. Since self.collectionView is optional type swift compiler can't catch that.

Comment: I moved it to viewDidLoad and the same error happens. I added a print statement and printed out self.collectionView and it is already allocated and probably also initialized at that point:

Optional(<UICollectionView: 0x7fe81e00cc00; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe81d115260>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe81d115290>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewLayout: 0x7fe81d117b10>)